# Manually deploy WAR file into Tomcat 7

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, soap, java-ee-6

I've been struggling with this problem for a long time. The actual problem is that after I create a dynamic web project in Eclipse, using CXF and Tomcat as a server, I want to be able to export this project int a war file and manually deploy it into Apache Tomcat. The actual thing is that after I deploy the war file on the Tomcat server I can't open it. I am copying it into tomcat-7.0.41\webapps folder. I am using CXF 2.7.5 and tomcat 7.0 . Can you please answer me why I can't open it from Tomcat 7 :(

Comment: Did you delete any older versions from the server? Did you try stopping and starting the rest server?

Comment: Yes, I've restarted the server every time I upload the war file. Also I am running the server from "portable" version that does not need installation.

Comment: Are you getting an exception? It's not clear based on your question.  are you using a build tool of some kind?